# Java Migration 1.6 to 1.8 run time Error

Tags: java, migration, runtime-error, runtimeexception

we are currently migrating Java 1.6 to 1.8 on Jboss 6.1.0 Final.
building the application from ANT, the build succeeded without any errors but during run time the below issue is being faced when we access few .jsp pages.

```
2016-08-22 15:16:53,451 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/].[jsp]] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:446) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:607) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [:6.1.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [servlet-api.jar:6.0.0.20100216-M2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:639) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:576) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:621) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:137) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:177) [struts.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:756) [struts.jar:1.1]
```

Comment: Looks like part of it is being compiled with 1.6? Judging by the stacktrace

Comment: @dylan meeus, could you please elaborate on the above being compiled with 1.6

Comment: Look at the stacktrace (first line: `at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92) [:6.1.0.Final]`)